# how to draw dot with border in android studio for intro slider?

Tags: android

I want to draw dots for each slide in intro slider for simple dot I use this code and its work:

```
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.dot_active));
```

but I want to draw a transparent dot with white border for inactive dots.Like this image:
[image: dots]
 How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In your layout.xml file, add this view for dots.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:alpha=".5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layoutDots"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

In your Activity or Fragment, use this code to addDots,

```
private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
private TextView[] dots;
private int no_of_dots = 4;

private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
    dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
    dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

    dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_dots; i++) {
        dots[i] = new TextView(this);
        dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        dots[i].setTextSize(35);
        dots[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(Color.WHITE));
        dots[i].setAlpha(0);
        dots[i].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle_background));
        dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
    }

    if (dots.length > 0)
        dots[currentPage].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
}
```

Add this in drawable folder. And set it as background for inactive dots

**circle_background.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#78d9ff"/>
</shape>
```

**Edit:**

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/

In above tutorial, author has explained how to implement Intro ImageSlider using viewpager. You can see how he has implemented dots layout as well. 
I had implemented using this as reference. Hope it helps.

Comment: this code draw a dot with inactive_color or active_color , but i want the inactive dots be transparent and have white border

Comment: You want dots to be transparent and white border? You mean make them invisible?

Comment: How do you want your active and inactive dots exactly? Background color, border color and transparency (alpha) values

Comment: I add picture I want to question

Comment: I have edited my answer. Add circle_background.xml to drawable folder. I have updated addButtons function as well. Try it out

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have a question in layout.xml file there is a View and a LinearLayout? this didn't work for me maybe my layout.xml is wrong

Comment: I have added LinearLayout of dots to that View in your layout.xml.  It should work. It doesn't show anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171645/discussion-between-zara-t-and-okcomputer-kid).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @okcomputer_kid , I use below codes to solve the problem:

active_dot_slider.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="2"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="@color/dotHome_active" />

</shape>
```

transparent_circle.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="2"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

and finally showDots method:

```
private void showDots(int pageNumber){
        TextView [] dots = new TextView[viewPager.getAdapter().getCount()];
        layoutDots.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i] = new TextView(getContext());
            dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            dots[i].setTextSize(30);
            dots[i].setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            dots[i].setBackground((i!=pageNumber)?
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transparent_circle):getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.active_dot_slider));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
            dots[i].setLayoutParams(params);
            layoutDots.addView(dots[i]);
        }
    }
```